# Поиск по столбцу с XML данными в MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Каким образом можно делать select по столбцам с xml-данными?
Есть некий столбец:

[image: Example]

Каким образом надо написать select, чтобы при выводе получить только данные, содержащие, например '%Оплата%'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы c xml нужно использовать xquery

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column.value('(/Language/Ru)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') LIKE N'%Оплата%'
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем уверен, насчёт MSSQL, но в Oracle можно попробовать конструкцию    `LIKE('%Оплата%')` должно бы и сработать, либо порезать строки с помощью substr.

Comment: Дело в том, что эти данные не являются текстом и через LIKE он ничего не фильтрует.

Comment: Возможно надо сначала преобразовать этот столбец, а уже потом выбирать, но проблема в том, что я не могу найти инфы, как это сделать :/

Comment: на англоязычной версии есть ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605854/ms-sql-xml-data-type-convert-to-text?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa собственно и ниже дали его